# Which devices support adobe air?

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, air, adobe

I am willing to switch my old flash and web apps/games to adobe air so they can also be available to mobile users and need to know how known adobe air is among devices. So my efforts don't get waste.

Comment: [Please Google it first](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Which+devices+support+adobe+air+apps%3F&oq=Which+devices+support+adobe+air+apps%3F&aqs=chrome.0.57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Adobe AIR Technical Specs](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/tech-specs.html)

I hope that helps.

Comment: Its much easier on their page

Answer (score 3):

There are mobile devices running FlashPlayer natively. Like you stated, it's possible to compile an AIR application to a native app which allows you to publish for Android and IOS devices, so that makes the reach even bigger.

**FlashPlayer capable devices:**
http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/flashruntimes/certified-devices.html

**Android devices:**
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices

**IOS devices:**
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices

*Small note: There are no devices running Adobe AIR(?) correct me if I'm wrong*

Comment: Indeed, no devices run Adobe AIR. Addition: With Adobe Flash Builder someone can create apps for iOS, Android and Blackberry OS using the flex framework.

Comment: You can run AIR on Android: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.air&hl=en - this was a requirement in earlier versions (Air 2.0?) when compiling for that platform. It's not quite the same as air elsewhere, though - more a support library for native apps compiled from Flash/Flex.

Answer (score 0):

AIR itself is not really "known" among mobile devices that I've encountered practically. Instead, AIR will compile to a **native** app which means an .IPA for iOS or an .APK for Android. In that context it is not technically "AIR" on those devices but the native binary.

If you download the free FlashDevelop here http://www.flashdevelop.org/ you can use their pre-made AIR for Mobile template to see how these are compiled.

**Windows 8 / Metro / Surface**
The Adobe roadmap focus on Flash Player for Metro / Windows 8 but Adobe has said elsewhere that AIR will be the vehicle for this (http://blogs.adobe.com/digitalmedia/2011/09/flash-support-on-windows-8-and-metro/) but do not yet have firm releases / support http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/whitepapers/roadmap.html.

**Blackberry**
There is a Blackberry SDK for Blackberry 10 and Playbook. I have not played with these, but you can find out more at https://developer.blackberry.com/air/